# Is there a constant missing in acceleration (derivative of velocity)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If velocity function is `v(t) = t^2`, the derivative (acceleration) is `a(t) = 2t`.

I wonder whether is there a constant missing? Because

```
v(0) = 0^2 = 0
v(1) = 1^2 = 1
v(2) = 2^2 = 4
v(3) = 3^2 = 9

a(0) = 2*0 = 0
a(1) = 2*1 = 2
a(2) = 2*2 = 4
a(3) = 2*3 = 6
```

To me it seems that `a(1)` should be `1` because `v(1) - v(0) = 1`, also `v(2) - v(1) = 3` makes `a(2) = 3`. So if I was to use acceleration as an example, the equation should have been:

```
a(t) = 2t - 1
```

I know constant does not play a role in calculating derivatives or slope of line, but the constant is implicitly removed in the velocity-acceleration example.

Is that correct?

Comment: Why does $v(1)-v(0)=1$ mean $a(1)=1$ and not $a(0)=1$ (or $a(0.5)=1$)? The acceleration is increasing all the time, right?

Comment: @bof I guess the equations were wrongly formed, editing.

Comment: @bof Nonetheless I take the way we derives velocity from distance. At time `0s` distance is `0m` and velocity is `0m/s`, at time `1s` distance is `1m` and speed is `1m/s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration you get after differentiation is actually the instantaneous acceleration, and so you cannot equate the average acceleration directly.

However, if you do the average of the instantaneous accelerations at the two end points, that'd work. Here, it will be $\dfrac12(2+0)=1$ as you expected.

---

There is no constant missing, the definition is correct. And this average part works only in certain cases, for instance when your original function is a quadratic, meaning the derivative is linear. Since the derivative is linear, it increases with a constant rate, and so you can just take the average rate between the end points.

Consider a linear sequence or an arithmetic progression, $a_n=bn+c$, then the average of the first $n$ terms is
$$\dfrac{S_n}{n}=\dfrac12(a+a_n)$$
which is just the average of the first and last terms.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand that constants diminish as delta approaches 0, but when using acceleration as an example and calculating by examples, I think the constant should stay up to the point when we explain how it diminishes as time interval gets smaller. I also think that the definition that "acceleration is the first derivative of velocity" is somewhat incomplete because of the lacking of the constant. If that is the case I wonder why no text even bother to mention this.

Comment: Also would you explain how does the "average of the instantaneous acceleration" part work for other intervals? Where was the 1/2 part from?

Comment: @dz902: I have edited my answer.

Comment: I think I get the 1/2 part. Also the "change" and "instantaneous change" part are ok. Maybe velocity and acceleration were not very good examples to form an intuition of the derivatives as often the unit of velocity is bound with a fixed interval like per seconds or per hour, and this can create confusion over "average change" and "instant change". Thanks!